# Creating an advanced CSS nth-child selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a bunch of tiles that look like this:

[image]

The way I'm currently targeting the blue ones is like this:

```
#recent ul li:nth-child(3),
#recent ul li:nth-child(4),
#recent ul li:nth-child(9) {
    width: 49.79166666666667%;
    margin: 0 0 0 0.41666666666667%;
}
```

Is there a way in CSS to make a selector that takes that pattern into account, for if I wanted to add 60 tiles? So that I don't have to keep specifying exact values? I know how to select every 2nd, or third etc, but not something where the pattern changes.

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: can you insert every row into a container element? like div?

Comment: That's a last resort - I was wondering whether or not it could be done purely in CSS

Comment: Those `width` and `margin` values look really crazy, and will probably result in cross-browser issues caused by rounding errors... what are you trying to achieve? I think if you did `box-sizing:border-box`, you could just set `width:50%`.

Answer (score 4):

From your diagram, it looks like in every set of 6 li items, you want to target the 3rd and 4th....try this:

```
#recent ul li:nth-child(6n+3),
#recent ul li:nth-child(6n+4)
```

[dev.mozilla link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child)

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Re67v/)

Comment: this takes the 4th and 5th, doesn't it? :)

Comment: yes you were right, slight typo. I've also added a jsfiddle. Also its worth noting this is not supported in IE8 or less

Comment: If the question is asking about how to create advanced selectors with `:nth-child()`, with a partially working demo already in place, then IE8 support is probably not a big deal at all. Also, those should be single colons.